# how can i sum my options like a calculator?

Tags: javascript, performance, calculator, calculation, feedback

i am making a menu calculator that gives you the total of the products, but im stuck cause i don't know where to start, [image: my calculator app]

i was thinking to use if else statement and put multiple id's on every button and somehow calculate the total but i think is very inefficient so if someone have a better idea, it would be perfect

!! oh by the way !!
im generating the buttons elements with create-element and appendchild .

here is my code

////////////////////HTML//////////////////////////

```
<body>
    <div class="icons-container" id="container">

    </div>
    <div class="displayer">
        <p>price</p>
        <p>total</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////Javascript//////////////////////////

```
nombres = ['Kg','Taco','Dorado','1LtCSM','1/2CSM','Boing','Cafe','Refresco'];
precios = [440,30,24,50,25,20,20,25];

Total = [];


const element = document.querySelector('.icons-container');

for(i=0;i<=7;i++){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    
    
    div.classList.add('cuadro');
    div.appendChild(h3);
    h3.textContent = `${nombres[i]}`;
    h3.classList.add('icon-text');
    element.appendChild(div);
    
};
```

i haven't tried nothing but i was thinking to use if else and add different id's on every button to differentiate each one,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using an array of objects, and a `.forEach()` loop, we solve all your problems, in a simpler way.

[image]

with this solution, there **isn't** any need to add `class=""` or `id=""` to every button because we used a simple concept called `Closures` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures which makes `.forEach()` and `.addEventListener()` together work very fine here!

```js
const menuData = [{
    name: "Kg",
    price: 440,
  },
  {
    name: "Taco",
    price: 30,
  },
  {
    name: "Dorado",
    price: 24,
  },
  {
    name: "1LtCSM",
    price: 50,
  },
  {
    name: "1/2CSM",
    price: 25,
  },
  {
    name: "Boing",
    price: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "Cafe",
    price: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "Refresco",
    price: 25,
  },
];

generateGrid(menuData, document.querySelector(".icons-container"));

function generateGrid(menuData, parent) {
  let total = 0;

  menuData.forEach((menuItem) => {
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    const h3 = document.createElement("h3");

    btn.appendChild(h3);
    parent.appendChild(btn);

    h3.textContent = menuItem.name;

    const priceEl = document.getElementById("price");
    const totalEl = document.getElementById("total");

    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      total += menuItem.price;

      priceEl.textContent = menuItem.price;
      totalEl.textContent = total;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
/* use your own css here, this is just for demo purposes */

body,
.icons-container {
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.icons-container,
.displayer {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.displayer>div {
  text-align: center;
}

.displayer div>div {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons-container">
  <!-- JS will put the divs here -->
</div>

<div class="displayer">
  <div>
    <p>price</p>
    <div id="price">0</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>total</p>
    <div id="total">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dude that's amazing, the forEach loop and the closures never crossed my mind, im not used to use it but works perfectly thank you, and how did you make that gif example, did you use figma or what?.

Comment: @DanielSanchezIslas sorry for the late response (I was busy these days), yes I used a simple video recorder called "OBS STUDIO" and edited it online with "EZGIF" just for compression so the gif will take less than 2MB so I can add it in the answer. nothing crazy, no Figma, just HTML CSS, and video recording.